# How to handle invalid lat/long with st_makepoint

Tags: sql, snowflake

I am trying to create geohashes from lat/longs but some of my lat/long data is incorrect. I can't find a way to handle these rows.

With:

```
select
  user_id
  , st_makepoint(user_longitude, user_latitude) user_geohash
from
  users
```

The error I'm receiving is:

> GeoJSON::Point: Invalid Lng/Lat pair: '32.1264,114.067'.

Eventually what I'm trying to pull is:

```
st_geohash(try_to_geography(st_makepoint(campus_longitude, campus_latitude))) campus_geohash
```

Does anyone have an idea for how I can handle these rows with messed up data?

Comment: switch your axis order from long/lat to lat/long and all should be fine

Comment: If some of the data is lat/lon and some is lon/lat, you have a data entry issue. Adding range checks *before* entry is probably wisest, but you cant use SQL to test in a `CASE` before using `ST_MakePoint`.